# Break the string in positions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to split the string according to the positions not a string array just single string. I wrote following code and works fine. But is there any way to do it handy manner ?

```js
function breakString(str, postion) {
 var newStr;
 var arr = [], res = [];
 arr = str.split("");
 for(var i = 0; i < postion; i++){
  res[i] = arr[i]
  newStr = res.join("");
 }

 return newStr; 
}

console.log(breakString("rasika", 3));
```

Comment: console.log('rasika'.substr(0, 3)) does the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the 2 ways that I can suggest you to use for this task.

✓ Using **slice()** method.

✓ Using **split(), slice()** & **join()** methods in conjunction.

> http://rextester.com/CNVUP86671

```
var name = "rasika";

console.log(name.slice(0,3)); // ras
console.log(name.split("").slice(0, 3).join("")); // ras
```

Answer (score -1):

**easy manner**

```js
var arr = "Rasika";
console.log(arr.substring(0,3));
```

Comment: I think I gave same answer.